# How to set session into function need to store header into function

Tags: php

```
session_start();

function refresh(){

$_session['refresh'] = header('Refresh: 5, url=https://www.google.com);

}
```

I want to store header function in session how can i store

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you wanna do? You actually cannot "store" header function itself. This function sends headers to the browser by its behavior

Comment: You can't "store a function" mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do like this:

```
function refresh() {
    $_SESSION['refresh'] = array('rate'=>5, 'url'=>'https://www.google.com');
}


// Check if refresh session Exists 
if( isset($_SESSION['refresh']) && count($_SESSION['refresh']) > 0 ) {
    header("Refresh: ".$_SESSION['refresh']['rate'].";url=".$_SESSION['refresh']['url']."");
}
```

**NOTE:** There is not space between `;` and `url`

Comment: @user4464505 have you used `$_session`? if yes then please use `$_SESSION`

Comment: @user4464505 Note that there is no space between `;` and `url`

Comment: @user4464505 If it works then please close this thread to accept this answer.

Comment: for vote up requires 15 reputation hve only 12 now ;(

Comment: @user4464505 I don't mean by vote up, i mean accept answer to click on check mark to close this thread.